# Автозагрузка приложения в Windows 8-10

Tags: windows, wpf

Написана программа в WPF.

Эту программу необходимо запускать при загрузке операционной системы. Делаю программным путем запись в нужный раздел реестра. После этого в диспетчере задач вижу, что программа устанавливается в автозапуск, однако при следующей загрузке системы не стартует.  Раньше (например, в Windows 7) никаких проблем не было. Возможно не хватает привилегий.

Как сделать программным путем автозапуск с правами администратора? Может в этом проблема?

Пробовал помещать ярлык программы в папку Автозагрузка. Никакой реакции!

Comment: В свойствах приложения(exe) выставьте права

Comment: А как именно вы помещаете ярлык в каталог «Автозагрузка»? Покажите ваш код.

Comment: И зачем вашей программе админские права, если не секрет?

Comment: Программа должна быть подписана. Либо через службы.

Comment: Какие права Вы имеете в виду? Я внедрял манифест приложения в доступом requireAdministrator и даже highestAvailable. Никакого эффекта.

Answer (score 1):

Вот код добавления своей программы в автозагрузку (Windows 10)

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");
regKey.SetValue("MyApp", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
regKey.Close();
```

Comment: Уважаемый MaximK, именно так я и делал в коде.

Comment: В какую ветку вы пытаетесь добавить ключ? CurrentUser или LocalMachine?

Comment: Пробовал и туда и туда. В принципе для работы хватило бы добавления в текущего пользователя.

Comment: Пользователь под которым происходит добавление НЕ администратор?

Comment: Конечно администратор!

Comment: @PWLSoft у меня тоже не работает. Как вы решили проблемму?

Comment: Проблему решил созданием программным путем задания в Планировщике задач. Был создан класс на основе класса **Interop.TaskScheduler**. Я использую этот класс в установщике своей программы и он создает это задание.  Оно запускает мое приложение с наивысшими правами. И вся проблема ушла. Microsoft очередной раз перемудрили с этой безопасностью.